# running standalone java application on server

Tags: java, proxy, host

I have to create the following setup :

1. The server displays a web page to the user.
2. The user clicks on a button on the page.(Request is sent to the server).
3. The server then starts a stand alone java application on the clients behalf. This application is meant for making certain transaction on a different web page. So this new webpage must be shown to the user on the client machine(in a new broswer tab).
4. The client can then interact with the web page. All clicks made by the client on the web page ( all generated requests ) must pass through the application running on the server(the application has a proxy feature). The responses must also be returned to the client.

Is this setup possible? How? What technology must I use?

EDIT :

Is the following a better solution :

Host the application on a proxy server and configure the browser to go through the proxy server. Will I be able to view the webpage on the client in this way. Again what server/technology would i use?

Comment: Who gave you this task? How does he answers your questions?

Comment: I think this is totally wrong headed.  You can do this in the context of the app server with a user session.

Answer (score 1):

This can be created like any simple Web Application in java. Following technologies should be sufficient :

- JSP or any other client view like Velocity
- HTTPServlets : Assuming working with HTTP protocol.
- Web.xml : This file is required to configure servlets and any other proxy/Filter you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

You need a client on comuter A connecting to a Server on computer B which you design in a way it can access the application on computer C and control it, so you will need the APi of the application or to design the application wo it can be controled by the server. At the end you are trying to develop something like a [NetViewer](http://www.netviewer.com/de/) like a tool for window sharing, can not you use any 3rd part tool? do you really need to implement this.

Comment: The tool I have developed is actually a web application scanner that scans only those pages which the user visits(through a proxy server). I just have to host it on a server so that clients can just provide the website/ipaddress and the server will do a scan for them. I can use any technology/tool which is free/opensource.

Answer (score 0):

Like duffymo said above, I really think this is headed off in the wrong direction.

Unless I am completely missing something here you are trying to get a server to redirect someone to another page just so you can save what they are doing on those other pages?

This can be done a lot simpler using sessions.  The server does everything itself so there is no re-direction, which on some browsers would cause a security page to show up, and it is much simpler to code.  All you need to do is pass the session back from the client and have the server keep track of that session.